# Count duplicates in column and add them to new col Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

im trying to count duplicates and then drop.cuplicates to get dataframe without duplicates but heve extra col in which we have number that represents how many duplicates there were

**from**

```py
       id  letter
0  665639  AAAAAA
1  665639  AAAAAA
2  665639  AAAAAA
3  665639  AAAAAA
5  702090  BBBBBB
6  702092  CCCCCC
```

**to**

```py
       id  letter   count
0  665639  AAAAAA     4
1  665639  AAAAAA     4
2  665639  AAAAAA     4
3  665639  AAAAAA     4
5  702090  BBBBBB     1
6  702092  CCCCCC     1
```

**and after**

df.drop.duplicates(subset=['id'] ,inplace=True)

```py
       id  letter   count
0  665639  AAAAAA     4
5  702090  BBBBBB     1
6  702092  CCCCCC     1
```

my approach was:

```py
cols = ['id','letter']
df['count'] = df.groupby(cols)['id'].transform('size')
```

but when im doing this i get dataframe that has only 1's in count

Comment: your command works fine on mine. Change your code to ```df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'],inplace=True)```

Comment: If you get only 1's in count, it may be because you've run the command twice? The first time you drop all the duplicates and df contains only one row per couple id-letter, then the second time you have only 1's in count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first create the count of duplicates

```
df['Count'] = 1
df.groupby(['id','letter']).Count.count().reset_index()
```

And then drop the duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
transform operator recombines data after aggregation. Hence it returns all rows. Hence for all rows try:
```

```
df['count']=df.groupby('id')['letter'].transform('count')#all rows ;
```

direct use of a method  in groupby  summarises  the columns which it is applied to. Since groupby returns a series, `.to_frame()` converts  it to dataframe.If name is given  the resulting series is renamed thus. For summarised  outcome try:

```
df.groupby('id')['letter'].value_counts().to_frame('count')#summarised
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A': [665639, 665639, 665639, 665639, 702090, 702092],
         'B': ['AAAAAA', 'AAAAAA', 'AAAAAA', 'AAAAAA', 'BBBBBB', 'CCCCCC']})
df.value_counts().reset_index(name='counts')
```

If you only need repeated values:

`df.value_counts().reset_index(name='counts').query('counts > 1')`